# sql server job failed but this works when running manually

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

this when run manually works but when I put this in a job step in a sql server job, it failed. the error code is:'Incorrect syntax near '\'. SQLState 42000 (Error 102) the step failed'

```
 \\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "2|3"
```

it is running this code that is receiving the parameters. Cant' see why it would work manual the same not ok in sql server job.

```
 if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
            {
                Helper.AddtoLogFile("Parameter is : " + args[0]);
                string[] arrProgType = args[0].Split('|');

                if (arrProgType != null && arrProgType.Length > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrProgType.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "1")
                        {
                            Order.RunOrder();
                        }
                        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "2")
                        {
                            Shipment.RunShipment();
                        }
                        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "3")
                        {
                            Acknowledgments.RunAcknowledgments();
                        }
                        if (arrProgType[i].Trim().TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"') == "4")
                        {
                            Invoices.RunInvoices();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Helper.AddtoLogFile("------ No program type parameter found");
            }
            Helper.AddtoLogFile("-------Program Ends ----------");
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could I run this? but its only working on for the first line, is there any cleanup neede? \\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "2"

\\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user the job is running as does not have permission to access `\\server-sql\c$`, you need to run the job as a user with permissions or set up a network share that the user the job runs as can access and use that instead.

The reason it works when you manually run it is the code is running as "you" instead of the job'search user.

Comment: this could be but is there any way to verify that it's a permissions issue?